# Embedded power bi in Donnet nuke

Tags: powerbi, dotnetnuke

This is not exactly a programming question but more of a design concern, after all my research i could not find anything, as do not understand much about DNN or any CMS architecture.

We need to embed power bi in DNN CMS website for the each of our website users(who are our customers), based on their individual data. The KPIs could vary for each customer in number and KPIs.

I know DNN store has a [product](https://store.dnnsoftware.com/home/product-details/power-bi-embedded) for embedding in power bi, but can individual KPIS be deployed for each user. There would be some common visuals for each user and some user specific visuals.

All i am looking for is some guidance to understand if this is feasible and scalable. Any feedback and reference is highly welcome.

Answer (score 0):

As I don't know the product I canot speak for it, but when I read the page that is linked I find

> Authorization
>   Simply provide your username, password, and Client ID.

There is also a link titled "Ask a question" - I would try to get an answer there.

Finally: Why not download the trial version and test it?